# Arduino OTA Firmware Backup ESP32

Tags: arduino, backup, firmware, ota, esp32

It is widely known that you can update firmware over-the-air using `<Update.h>` functionality: receive blob size over the network, call `Update.begin(blob_size)`, consecutively call `Update.write()` until its done, then call `Update.end()`, and restart the board.

But is there a way to do a backup of current firmware binary using WiFi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "no", there's no support for dumping the firmware over WiFi.

I've not looked at how WiFi Update is implemented so I'm not saying it can't be done at all - just that you're going to have to implement it yourself. Just like Update, if the sketch doesn't already support it, it is likely not possible at all (so you can't backup from an ESP32 flashed with just any old sketch).

Comment: Well, that's what I expected, but had hopes anyway =3